# How to speed up query with joins

Tags: postgresql, performance, join, query-performance

I have a couple of tables that I need to join. I have an **employees** table (~ 400K rows), a **companies** table (~10 million rows) and a **employee_companies** table which stores where someone works.

Basically, I need to get all the employees that match some conditions (they work on a company that has a website, are located in a certain country, etc). I made a query to get this, but it's taking too long. I need to speed it up.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT "employees".* 
FROM "employees" 
INNER JOIN "employee_companies" ON "employee_companies"."employee_id" = "employees"."id" 
INNER JOIN "companies" ON "companies"."id" = "employee_companies"."company_id" 
WHERE (employee_companies.employee_id IS NOT NULL)
AND (companies.website IS NOT NULL) 
AND (employees.country = 'Uruguay') 
ORDER BY employees.connections DESC
```

This is the plan for that query:

```
Unique  (cost=877170.24..880752.72 rows=62304 width=1064) (actual time=24023.736..26001.876 rows=73318 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=877170.24..877326.00 rows=62304 width=1064) (actual time=24023.733..24305.989 rows=77579 loops=1)
        Sort Key: employees.connections DESC, employees.id, employees.name, employees.link, employees.role, employees.area, employees.profile_picture, employees.summary, employees.current_companies, employees.previous_companies, employees.skills, employees.education, employees.languages, employees.volunteer, employees.groups, employees.interests, employees.search_vector, employees.secondary_search_vector, employees.email_status, employees.languages_count, employees.role_hierarchy
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 85816kB
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2642.38..843246.15 rows=62304 width=1064) (actual time=139.870..23056.234 rows=77579 loops=1)
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=2641.95..221744.50 rows=77860 width=1068) (actual time=139.841..22617.587 rows=77579 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (employees.id = employee_companies.employee_id)
                    ->  Seq Scan on employees  (cost=0.00..212178.88 rows=409672 width=1064) (actual time=8.145..22369.166 rows=393725 loops=1)
                          Filter: ((country)::text = 'Uruguay'::text)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 1075
                    ->  Hash  (cost=1666.42..1666.42 rows=78042 width=8) (actual time=44.675..44.675 rows=78042 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 131072  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 4073kB
                          ->  Seq Scan on employee_companies  (cost=0.00..1666.42 rows=78042 width=8) (actual time=0.007..22.901 rows=78042 loops=1)
                                Filter: (employee_id IS NOT NULL)
              ->  Index Scan using companies_pkey on companies  (cost=0.43..7.97 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=77579)
                    Index Cond: (id = employee_companies.company_id)
                    Filter: (website IS NOT NULL)
Planning time: 1.957 ms
Execution time: 26025.045 ms
```

And these are the relevant indexes that I have on my table:

**employees**:

```
"employees_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"ix_employees_country" btree (country)
```

**companies**:

```
"companies_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"empty_websites" btree (website) WHERE website IS NULL
"index_companies_on_website" btree (website)
"not_empty_websites" btree (website) WHERE website IS NOT NULL
```

**employee_companies**:

```
"employee_companies_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"index_employee_companies_on_company_id" btree (company_id)
"index_employee_companies_on_employee_id" btree (employee_id)
"index_employee_companies_on_employee_id_and_company_id" btree (employee_id, company_id)
"not_empty_employee_id" btree (employee_id) WHERE employee_id IS NOT NULL
```

Is there any other better way to do what I want that is more efficient/performant?

Thanks!

Comment: `index_employee_companies_on_employee_id` is useless you already have that index with `index_employee_companies_on_employee_id_and_company_id`

Comment: You "employee_companies" doesn't need an anonymous `id` as a PKEY. You can use `(company_id, employee_id)` as the PKEY. That already guarantees that `employee_id is not null`. It wouldn't make sense for an intermediate table representing a many-to-many relationship to have null values in either column. You might need a second index `(employee_id, company_id)`, but nothing more. That won't speed up your query, but will speed up inserting values on the table.

Comment: @joanolo yes you are right! my mistake. I have 394800 employees on the database, but 73116 are the ones that I care about (the ones that work for a company that has a website). Sorry for that.

Comment: remove the useless `employee_id IS NOT NULL`  and update your explain, you're messing with the query optimizer for something that can't survive your inner join anyway

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on some guess-simulations, I think you can slightly improve your query by:

1. Avoiding the outer `DISTINCT` clause (although there will be an implicitly `DISTINCT`).
2. Sub-selecting a part of the data so that less is needed to `JOIN`.

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT  
    employees.* 
FROM 
    employees 
WHERE
    employee_id IN
    (SELECT 
        -- Choose all employees from companies with website
        employee_id 
     FROM 
        employee_companies
        JOIN companies ON companies.company_id = employee_companies.company_id
     WHERE
        companies.website IS NOT NULL
    )
    -- Now filter only employees from 'Germany'
    AND employees.country = 'Germany' 
ORDER BY 
    employees.connections DESC ;
```

---

The data used to produce the simulation is the following one:

Table and index definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(
    employee_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    country text,
    connections integer,
    something_else text
) ;

CREATE INDEX idx_employee_country 
   ON employees (country) ;

CREATE TABLE companies
(
    company_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    website text,
    something_else text
) ;

CREATE INDEX not_empty_websites 
    ON companies(company_id, website) WHERE website IS NOT NULL ;

CREATE TABLE employee_companies
(
    employee_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES employees(employee_id),
    company_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES companies(company_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (employee_id, company_id)
) ;

CREATE INDEX company_employee
    ON employee_companies(company_id, employee_id) ;
```

1.000.000 companies (changing to 10M doesn't make a big difference). I assume 90% have a website.

```
INSERT INTO 
   companies
   (company_id, website)
SELECT
   generate_series(1, 1000000), 
   CASE WHEN random() > 0.1 THEN 'web.com' END AS website ;
```

80k employees (about 10% are Germans)

```
INSERT INTO
   employees 
   (employee_id, country, connections)
SELECT
    generate_series(1, 80000),
    case (random()*10)::integer
    when 0 then 'Germany'
    when 1 then 'United Kingdon'
    when 2 then 'United States'
    else 'Angola'
    end AS country,
    (random()*10)::integer AS connections ;
```

200K employees x companies (this means that people have worked in about 3 companies, on average):

```
INSERT INTO 
    employee_companies
    (employee_id, company_id)
SELECT DISTINCT
    (random()*79999)::integer + 1,
    (random()*999999)::integer + 1
FROM
    generate_series (1, 200000) ;
```

You can check a downsized version of this simulation at *[dbfiddle here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=32705d6d64e6c554b6852da276afd804)*.  If this simulated data is sufficiently similar to your scenario, changing the query makes a 3x improvement with regard to server-execution time. I'd suggest you give it a try.

---

Simulating data (scaled down by a factor of 25) a scenario more similar to your real one doesn't offer such a nice increase in performance... Nevertheless, it improves by a 1.5 factor.

Check it at this *[dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=10fad44682b530e7e7939f731a3cc1fa)*